# Cypress: How to Copy/Paste single text word from string to paste later

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress, copy-paste

I am new to stackoverflow so apologies if this is a bit all over the place but I can't seem to find any easy answer online for what seems like a pretty small task! :(

I am trying to Copy some data from a pop-up, that says something like "Congrats, Your Ref (REF1234) completed successfully" (just the REF1234 part) and copy it to paste into another field on the next screen... This is what I have so far, which hopefully makes sense to someone...

```
export function addRefToThing() {    
  cy.get('[class="ref-success"]').find(':selected').contains('REF').then(($clipboard) => {
    const copiedRef = $clipboard[0]._vClipboard.clipboardAction.text;

// <<filler steps, moving around pages>> //

    webpage.RefNo().type(copiedRef)})
```

This is pretty much as far as I've been able to get and pulling my hair out ... Looks like it's getting caught up at `-find :selected` but not actually sure it's even copying the data I want...

I'm pretty new to cypress so this is proving pretty confusing and if anyone has any good training material regarding this kind of request, that'd be awesome! Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```html
<div class="notification-group" style="width: 300px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;">
   <span>
      <div data-id="1" class="notification-wrapper" style="transition: all 300ms ease 0s;">
         <div class="notification-template notification success">
            <div class="notification-title">Successful</div>
            <div class="notification-content">Ref (REF123456789) created successfully</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to share the html of the element. Or if your webpage is public, can you add that to the question?

Comment: @AlapanDas <div class="vue-notification-group" style="width: 300px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;"><span><div data-id="1" class="vue-notification-wrapper" style="transition: all 300ms ease 0s;"><div class="vue-notification-template vue-notification success"><div class="notification-title">Successful</div> <div class="notification-content">Ref (REF12345678) created successfully</div></div></div></span></div>

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a regex to parse the ref.

Using `/\(REF([0-9]+)\)/` you get two matches,

- matches[0] is the whole "(REF123456789)""
- matches[1] is the inner group "123456789"

```js
cy.get('div.notification-content')
  .then($el => $el.text().match(/\(REF([0-9]+)\)/)[1])  // parsing step
  .then(ref => {
    webpage.RefNo().type(ref)
  })
```

In your function,

```js
export function addRefToRef() {    
  cy.get('[class="ref-success"]').find(':selected').contains('REF')
    .then(($clipboard) => {
      const copiedRef = $clipboard[0]._vClipboard.clipboardAction.text;
      const innerRef = copiedRef.match(/\(REF([0-9]+)\)/)[1];

      // <<filler steps, moving around pages>> //

      webpage.RefNo().type(innerRef)
    })
}
```

Comment: Awesome - I think this is progress thank you! However now I'm getting a different issue, not sure if I'll need to make a new ticket :') Now getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clipboardAction') on my const copiedRef step ... I have clipboardy installed but not sure if anything silly I'm forgetting or missing... Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't really tell you what `const copiedRef = $clipboard[0]._vClipboard.clipboardAction.text` is doing lol. I expect this is copy the text but I am totally new to all this and not sure if I have just taken this snippet from somewhere not looking at dependencies...

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')`

Comment: Ok, I was a bit suspicious of that clipboard code too. The `cy.get('div.notification-content')` block will work.

Comment: Hey so now I worked past this point but I get `cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: null` when trying to do the type(ref) step... Any ideas? O_o

Answer (score 0):

You can directly save the inner text value from the `notification-content` div and use it later. You don't have to use the clipboard method.

```js
//Some code that will trigger the notification
cy.get('.notification-content')
  .should('be.visible')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    cy.log(text) //prints Ref (REF123456789) created successfully
  })
```

In case if you want to save it and then use it later in the test, you can use alias `.as`:

```js
//Some code that will trigger the notification
cy.get('.notification-content')
  .should('be.visible')
  .invoke('text')
  .as('notificationText')
//Some other code
cy.get('@notificationText').then((notificationText) => {
  cy.log(notificationText) //prints Ref (REF123456789) created successfully
})
```

Or, if you want to assert the content:

1. Exact match:

```js
cy.get('.notification-content')
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('have.text', 'Ref (REF123456789) created successfully')
```

2. Partial Match

```js
cy.get('.notification-content')
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('include.text', 'REF123456789')
```

If you just want to extract the reference number then you have to first use `split` to get the second text and then use `slice` to remove the opening and closing brackets, something like this:

```js
//Some code that will trigger the notification      
cy.get('.notification-content').should('be.visible').invoke('text').as('notificationText')
//Some other code
cy.get('@notificationText').then((notificationText) => {
  cy.log(notificationText.split(' ')[1].slice(1,-1))  //REF123456789 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, will definitely help keep it tidier thanks! Yeah I experimented with this but could only seem to copy the whole element ("Ref (REF123456789) created successfully")... Whereas I want to take the contents in the brackets only as they will be used in a future step. I can't include full ref number as it changes each run.

Comment: I have updated my answer.